# Convergent subsequence in a bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Let $\Phi$ be an infinite family of monotonic real functions defined on $[a,b]$ such that $$\exists C,K\geq0:\forall\varphi\in \Phi\quad(\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|\varphi(x)|\leq C\quad\land\quad V_a^b(\varphi)\leq K)$$where $V_a^b(\varphi)$ is the total variation of $\varphi$ on its domain. I find it stated in Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Introductory Real Analysis* that, if $r_1,r_2,...,r_n,...$ are all the rational points of interval $[a,b]$, then the numbers $\varphi(r_1)$ are a bounded set (of course, since $\Phi$ is uniformly bounded), therefore there exists *a sequence of functions* $\{\varphi_n^{(1)}\}$ *converging at* $r_1$. *Similarly* $\{\varphi_n^{(1)}\}$ *contains a subsequence* $\{\varphi_n^{(2)}\}$ *converging at* $r_2$ as well as at $r_1$, which I think to mean that there exists a sequence $\{\varphi_n^{(1)}\}$, such that $\{\varphi_n^{(1)}(r_1)\}$ converges, containing a subsequence $\{\varphi_n^{(2)}\}\subset\{\varphi_n^{(1)}\}$ such that $\{\varphi_n^{(2)}(r_2)\}$ converges too, as well as $\{\varphi_n^{(2)}(r_1)\}$.

How can the existence of such a sequence $\{\varphi_n^{(1)}\}$ be verified? I suspect that Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem cannot be applied and do not see what else could be helpful. I heartily thank you for any answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as long as $\Phi$ is infinite, we can apply the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem. Consider any countable subset $\{\varphi_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset \Phi$. Then consider the sequence $a_n = \varphi_n(r_1)$. By assumption $a_n$ is bounded, so by the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem $a_n$ has a convergent subsequence $a_{n_k}$. Thus $\varphi_{n_k}$ is a sequence of functions such that $\varphi_{n_k}(r_1)$ is convergent.

Comment: @DavideZena No problem.